# How do I send a message e.g "Hello I am Some Packet" from Node.js Server(from port 55000) to other port(like maybe 8883) running on same computer?

Tags: node.js, tcp, port, mqtt

I am having a Happner Server, on IoT application. The Happner server is running on Port 55000, I would like that it send the data to MQTT Client/Broker running on the same computer. The Idea is to Integrate Happner with the MQTT client. I tried to look around online I found this module called ['dgram'](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html#dgram_socket_send_msg_offset_length_port_address_callback) I think it doesn't match exactly my need as I was not able to get the message after testing bellow code. Please suggest how I can make these 2 communicate(Happner and MQTT). I suppose I can just send packages on the Port the MQTT is running on and it receives it. Also please suggest is it reliable to send packets like that?

```
var dgram = require('dgram');
var client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

client.send('Hello3World!',0, 12, 12000, '127.0.0.1', function(err, bytes) {
    client.close();
});
```

Comment: Use the mqtt.js module to create an MQTT client and PUBLISH payloads to localhost (or 127.0.0.1).  https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with what you've asked in your question:

1. MQTT uses TCP not UDP so datagrams are not the right thing to use here. (There is MQTT-SN which can use UDP, but that is for really light weight applications and you will need a specialist broker)
2. There is normally no need to set the outgoing port number, the TCP stack will pick a unused ephemeral port when you open the connection.
3. You can't just send "Hello3World" to a MQTT broker, you need an existing session and the packet will need to conform to the MQTT [specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html) (e.g. a CONNECT/SUBSCRIBE/PUBLISH packet)
4. While you can choose to write your own MQTT client library it will be much easier to use an existing one, e.g [MQTT.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt)
5. Port 8883 is likely to either be MQTT over Websockets of MQTT over TLS both of which will require proper sessions to be created before you can start to setup the MQTT session. Another reason to use an existing client that can handle all this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a server same as client

```
var server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
```

and bind the server to the PORT of your choice before calling send() method like:

```
server.bind(8883, () => { 
    const size = server.ref(); 
});
```

and try to call the socket.send() method.
I think it will work.